# Spark dataframe transform multiple rows to column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am a novice to spark, and I want to **transform** below **source dataframe** (load from JSON file):

```
+--+-----+-----+
|A |count|major|
+--+-----+-----+
| a|    1|   m1|
| a|    1|   m2|
| a|    2|   m3|
| a|    3|   m4|
| b|    4|   m1|
| b|    1|   m2|
| b|    2|   m3|
| c|    3|   m1|
| c|    4|   m3|
| c|    5|   m4|
| d|    6|   m1|
| d|    1|   m2|
| d|    2|   m3|
| d|    3|   m4|
| d|    4|   m5|
| e|    4|   m1|
| e|    5|   m2|
| e|    1|   m3|
| e|    1|   m4|
| e|    1|   m5|
+--+-----+-----+
```

**Into** below **result dataframe**:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|A |m1|m2|m3|m4|m5|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| a| 1| 1| 2| 3| 0|
| b| 4| 2| 1| 0| 0|
| c| 3| 0| 4| 5| 0|
| d| 6| 1| 2| 3| 4|
| e| 4| 5| 1| 1| 1|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Here is the **Transformation Rule**:

1. The result dataframe is consisted with `A + (n major columns)` where the `major` columns names are specified by:

   ```
   sorted(src_df.map(lambda x: x[2]).distinct().collect())
   ```
2. The result dataframe contains `m` rows where the values for `A` column are provided by:

   ```
   sorted(src_df.map(lambda x: x[0]).distinct().collect())
   ```
3. The value for each major column in result dataframe is the value from source dataframe on the corresponding `A` and major
   (e.g. the count in Row 1 in source dataframe is mapped to the `box` where `A` is `a` and column `m1`)
4. The combinations of `A` and `major` in source dataframe has no duplication (please consider it a primary key on the two columns in SQL)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lets start with example data:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", 1, "m1"), ("a", 1, "m2"), ("a", 2, "m3"),
    ("a", 3, "m4"), ("b", 4, "m1"), ("b", 1, "m2"),
    ("b", 2, "m3"), ("c", 3, "m1"), ("c", 4, "m3"),
    ("c", 5, "m4"), ("d", 6, "m1"), ("d", 1, "m2"),
    ("d", 2, "m3"), ("d", 3, "m4"), ("d", 4, "m5"),
    ("e", 4, "m1"), ("e", 5, "m2"), ("e", 1, "m3"),
    ("e", 1, "m4"), ("e", 1, "m5")], 
    ("a", "cnt", "major"))
```

Please note that I've changed `count` to `cnt`. Count is a reserved keyword in most of the SQL dialects and it is not a good choice for a column name.

There are at least two ways to reshape this data:

- aggregating over DataFrame

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, max

  majors = sorted(df.select("major")
      .distinct()
      .map(lambda row: row[0])
      .collect())

  cols = [when(col("major") == m, col("cnt")).otherwise(None).alias(m) 
      for m in  majors]
  maxs = [max(col(m)).alias(m) for m in majors]

  reshaped1 = (df
      .select(col("a"), *cols)
      .groupBy("a")
      .agg(*maxs)
      .na.fill(0))

  reshaped1.show()

  ## +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ## |  a| m1| m2| m3| m4| m5|
  ## +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ## |  a|  1|  1|  2|  3|  0|
  ## |  b|  4|  1|  2|  0|  0|
  ## |  c|  3|  0|  4|  5|  0|
  ## |  d|  6|  1|  2|  3|  4|
  ## |  e|  4|  5|  1|  1|  1|
  ## +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ```
- `groupBy` over RDD

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import Row

  grouped = (df
      .map(lambda row: (row.a, (row.major, row.cnt)))
      .groupByKey())

  def make_row(kv):
      k, vs = kv
      tmp = dict(list(vs) + [("a", k)])
      return Row(**{k: tmp.get(k, 0) for k in ["a"] + majors})

  reshaped2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(grouped.map(make_row))

  reshaped2.show()

  ## +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ## |  a| m1| m2| m3| m4| m5|
  ## +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ## |  a|  1|  1|  2|  3|  0|
  ## |  e|  4|  5|  1|  1|  1|
  ## |  c|  3|  0|  4|  5|  0|
  ## |  b|  4|  1|  2|  0|  0|
  ## |  d|  6|  1|  2|  3|  4|
  ## +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ```

Answer (score 25):

Using zero323's dataframe,

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
("a", 1, "m1"), ("a", 1, "m2"), ("a", 2, "m3"),
("a", 3, "m4"), ("b", 4, "m1"), ("b", 1, "m2"),
("b", 2, "m3"), ("c", 3, "m1"), ("c", 4, "m3"),
("c", 5, "m4"), ("d", 6, "m1"), ("d", 1, "m2"),
("d", 2, "m3"), ("d", 3, "m4"), ("d", 4, "m5"),
("e", 4, "m1"), ("e", 5, "m2"), ("e", 1, "m3"),
("e", 1, "m4"), ("e", 1, "m5")], 
("a", "cnt", "major"))
```

you could also use

```
reshaped_df = df.groupby('a').pivot('major').max('cnt').fillna(0)
```

Comment: What does the "max" do here?

Comment: It handles duplicate values for "cnt". 

For example, if you have both
("a", 1, "m1") and ("a", 2, "m1"), this makes sure you would end up with the value 2 in the "m1" column.

Comment: Ah, so if I knew "cnt" always only had one value, then I could use select("cnt") instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is your original dataframe:

```
df.show()
```

> ```
> +--+-----+-----+
> |A |count|major|
> +--+-----+-----+
> | a|    1|   m1|
> | a|    1|   m2|
> | a|    2|   m3|
> | a|    3|   m4|
> | b|    4|   m1|
> | b|    1|   m2|
> | b|    2|   m3|
> | c|    3|   m1|
> | c|    4|   m3|
> | c|    5|   m4|
> | d|    6|   m1|
> | d|    1|   m2|
> | d|    2|   m3|
> | d|    3|   m4|
> | d|    4|   m5|
> | e|    4|   m1|
> | e|    5|   m2|
> | e|    1|   m3|
> | e|    1|   m4|
> | e|    1|   m5|
> +--+-----+-----+
> ```

Using pivot to reshape the data on "major", grouped by "A", and sum of "count" aggregated as value:

```
data = ( df.groupBy("A")
    .pivot("major")
    .sum("count") )

display(data)
```

> ```
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |A |m1|m2|m3|m4|m5|
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+
> | a| 1| 1| 2| 3| 0|
> | b| 4| 2| 1| 0| 0|
> | c| 3| 0| 4| 5| 0|
> | d| 6| 1| 2| 3| 4|
> | e| 4| 5| 1| 1| 1|
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+
> ```

Answer (score 0):

@TrentWoodbury's Answer is a good one and I voted for it. However, it doesn't work if the aggregate value is not an a number because `.max('cnt')` cannot perform the required aggregation. Also, max is potentially slower, or just unneeded, if you know you won't have duplicate values.

**The following works for all data types:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

reshaped_df = df.groupby('a') \
  .pivot('major') \ 
  .agg(first('cnt'))
```