# Pyspark - create new column from operations of DataFrame columns gives error "Column is not iterable"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame and I have tried many examples showing how to create a new column based on operations with existing columns, but none of them seem to work.

So I have t̶w̶o̶ one questions:

1- Why doesn't this code work?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

a = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(5, 5, 3)], ['A', 'B', 'C'])
a.withColumn('my_sum', F.sum(a[col] for col in a.columns)).show()
```

I get the error:
`TypeError: Column is not iterable`

**EDIT: Answer 1**

I found out how to make this work. I have to use the native Python `sum` function. `a.withColumn('my_sum', F.sum(a[col] for col in a.columns)).show()`. It works, but I have no idea why.

2- If there is a way to make this sum work, **how can I write a `udf` function to do this (and add the result to a new column of a DataFrame)?**

```
import numpy as np
def my_dif(row):
    d = np.diff(row) # creates an array of differences element by element
    return d.mean() # returns the mean of the array
```

I am using Python 3.6.1 and Spark 2.1.1.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the answer that you've found ?

Comment: @eliasah, the answer for me was to use the native Python `sum` function. I've edited my post with the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(5, 5, 3)], ['A', 'B', 'C'])
a = a.withColumn('my_sum', F.UserDefinedFunction(lambda *args: sum(args), IntegerType())(*a.columns))
a.show()

+---+---+---+------+
|  A|  B|  C|my_sum|
+---+---+---+------+
|  5|  5|  3|    13|
+---+---+---+------+
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. But can you also explain how the parameters work in that example? I am a bit confused by the `*args` and `*a.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this part `for col in a.columns` cuz you cannot iterate the result, so you must:

```
a = a.withColumn('my_sum', a.A + a.B + a.C)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, dannyeuu. But the problem is that in my real dataset I have hundreds of columns, so I can't type in one by one explicitly.

I got this from [the version 2 of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31955747/5420229), and I've also seen something like this in many other answers.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584812/pyspark-row-wise-function-composition