# How to flatten a pyspark dataframes that contains multiple rows per id?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with two id columns `id` and `id2`. Each `id` is repeated exactly `n` times. All `id`'s have the same set of `id2`'s. I'm trying to "flatten" the matrix resulting from each unique `id` into one row according to `id2`.

Here's an example to explain what I'm trying to achieve, my dataframe looks like this:

```
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| id | id2 | value1 | value2 |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 1   | 54     | 2      |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 2   | 0      | 6      |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 3   | 578    | 14     |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 2  | 1   | 10     | 1      |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 2  | 2   | 6      | 32     |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 2  | 3   | 0      | 0      |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 3  | 1   | 12     | 2      |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 3  | 2   | 20     | 5      |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
| 3  | 3   | 63     | 22     |
+----+-----+--------+--------+
```

The desired output is the following table:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | value1_1 | value1_2 | value1_3 | value2_1 | value2_2 | value2_3 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 54       | 0        | 578      | 2        | 6        | 14       |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 10       | 6        | 0        | 1        | 32       | 0        |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3  | 12       | 20       | 63       | 2        | 5        | 22       |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So, basically, for each unique `id` and for each column `col`, I will have `n` new columns `col_1`,... for each of the `n` `id2` values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732346/spark-dataframe-transform-multiple-rows-to-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark dataframe transform multiple rows to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732346/spark-dataframe-transform-multiple-rows-to-column)

Comment: It didn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

> In Spark 2.4 you can do this way

```
var df3 =Seq((1,1,54 , 2 ),(1,2,0  , 6 ),(1,3,578, 14),(2,1,10 , 1 ),(2,2,6  , 32),(2,3,0  , 0 ),(3,1,12 , 2 ),(3,2,20 , 5 ),(3,3,63 , 22)).toDF("id","id2","value1","value2")


scala> df3.show()
+---+---+------+------+
| id|id2|value1|value2|
+---+---+------+------+
|  1|  1|    54|     2|
|  1|  2|     0|     6|
|  1|  3|   578|    14|
|  2|  1|    10|     1|
|  2|  2|     6|    32|
|  2|  3|     0|     0|
|  3|  1|    12|     2|
|  3|  2|    20|     5|
|  3|  3|    63|    22|
+---+---+------+------+
```

using coalesce retrieve the first value of the id.

```
scala> var df4 = df3.groupBy("id").pivot("id2").agg(coalesce(first("value1")),coalesce(first("value2"))).orderBy(col("id"))

scala> val newNames = Seq("id","value1_1","value2_1","value1_2","value2_2","value1_3","value2_3")
```

Renaming columns

```
scala>  df4.toDF(newNames: _*).show()
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id|value1_1|value2_1|value1_2|value2_2|value1_3|value2_3|
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1|      54|       2|       0|       6|     578|      14|
|  2|      10|       1|       6|      32|       0|       0|
|  3|      12|       2|      20|       5|      63|      22|
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

rearranged column if needed. let me know if you have any question related to the same. HAppy HAdoop

Comment: @Achraf Oussidi accept the answer if its solve you purpose